# How does contextService work in flink internally?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently, I am using flink with kafka consumer. I listen task event changes(task creation event, task updation event, task close event) from kafka consumer stream. I have a use case where I need to check no **task updation** happened within **135 minutes** of **task creation**.
For this use case, I am using **contextService.setTimer(....)**.
Now, I am confused about the limitation of number of timer can be set.
i.e. if **100000** new task get created, then, **100000** timer will be set with different - different timestamp.

**is it feasible?**

**is it the best way to solve my use case?**

So Basically I want to know.

- How does contextService work internally?
- How many timer can be set(number of timers)?

Code

```
   private static class MatchFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long>, Object> {
        private ValueState<Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long>> taskState;

        public MatchFunction() {}

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration config) {
            ValueStateDescriptor<Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long>> stateDescriptor =
                    new ValueStateDescriptor<>("SLA Breach task event", TupleTypeInfo.getBasicTupleTypeInfo(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Long.class));
            taskState = getRuntimeContext().getState(stateDescriptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long> event, Context context, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
            Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long> previousEvent = taskState.value();
            String taskStatus = event.f1;
            String taskId = event.f0;
            long createdAt = event.f4;

            if(previousEvent != null && previousEvent.f1.equalsIgnoreCase(taskStatus)) {
                // might be duplicate event
                return;
            }

            if (previousEvent == null) {
                if (isNewEvent(event)) {
                    taskState.update(event);
                    long scheduleTime = Utils.getTimerTime(createdAt, Time.minutes(INT_135));
                    context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(scheduleTime);
                    logger.info("Adding event -> {} in taskState, Schedule time -> {}", event, new Date(scheduleTime));
                }
            } else {
                if (isUpdatedEvent(event)) {
                    // it's an UPDATE event, so event saved was the START event and has a timer
                    // the timer hasn't fired yet, and we can safely kill the timer

                

                    context.timerService().deleteEventTimeTimer(Utils.getTimerTime(createdAt, Time.minutes(INT_135)));
               
                    logger.info("Cancelled timer as Updation event was received for event - {} ", event);
                    // Update events have now been seen, we can clear the state
                    taskState.clear();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
            // no UPDATE event is received from past 135 minutes.
            

            Tuple5<String, String, String, String, Long> event = taskState.value();
            String taskId = event.f0;
           
            long createdAt = event.f4;
                // do something here after timer is received...
             
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A few key facts about Flink's timers:

- Timers are always keyed.
- Timers are inexpensive: you can have millions or billions of them.
- Timers can either live on the heap or in RocksDB.
- Timers are checkpointed, and will be restored after a failure.
- Timers are deduplicated at the level of (key, timestamp). In other words, for a specific key and timestamp, there will be at most one timer. Sometimes you can reduce the number of timers being created by leveraging this deduplication to coalesce timers.